# Cannot build a project in Eclipse C

Tags: eclipse

When clicking the hammer icon to build a C project, a popup comes out with a following message.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'Learn C'.
Illegal character in path at index 5: Learn C
```

As a C starter I honestly have no clue what that even means, so somebody please help me out..

Comment: As a wild guess, it doesn't like the whitespace in the path.

Comment: could you please post some code? that would help people help you

Comment: @JessPatton it was a really simple code; printf("Hello World.\n);